# Dynamic resize of kendo grid column not proper in IE10

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik-mvc

I am trying to resize the kendo grid column using a popup. It works well in all browsers except IE10. The header columns won't resize along with content columns in the grid.

I have created a sample. The difference can be seen when we run it on IE 10 and chrome

http://jsfiddle.net/pavancbz1/6LFYM/4/

The sample has a grid with 3 columns. The column indexes can be 0,1,2 in the pop up to resize the respective column.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        var window = $("#window"),
            undo = $("#undo")
                    .bind("click", function() {
                        window.data("kendoWindow").open();
                        undo.hide();
                    });

        var onClose = function() {
            undo.show();
        }

        if (!window.data("kendoWindow")) {
            window.kendoWindow({
                width: "280",
                title: "Pop up",
                actions: [
                   "Minimize",
                    "Maximize",
                    "Close"
                ],
                close: onClose
            });
        }
          $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Products",
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    }
                },
                pageSize: 5,

            },
            selectable: "multiple row",
            pageable: {
                buttonCount: 5
            },
            scrollable: true,
            groupable: false,
             resizable: true,
            columns: [
                {
                    field: "ProductName",
                    width: 'auto',
                    title: "Product Name"
                },
                {
                    field: "UnitPrice",
                    width: 'auto',
                    title: "Unit Price",
                    format: "{0:c}"
                },
                {
                    field: "UnitsInStock",
                    width: 'auto',
                    title: "Units In Stock"
                }
            ]
        });
         var IncreaseWidth = function (e) {
            if (e.type != "keypress" || kendo.keys.ENTER == e.keyCode) {
                var grid = $("#grid"),
                        Index = $("#index").val(),
                        tablewidth = grid.find('table').width();
                        grid.find('table').width(tablewidth+20);
                         columnwidth = grid.find('colgroup:first').find('col:eq(' + Index + ')').width();
                          grid.find('colgroup').find('col:eq(' + Index + ')').width(columnwidth+20);

            }
        },
            DecreaseWidth = function (e) {
                if (e.type != "keypress" || kendo.keys.ENTER == e.keyCode) {
                   var grid = $("#grid"),
                        Index = $("#index").val(),
                        tablewidth = grid.find('table').width();
                        grid.find('table').width(tablewidth-20);
                         columnwidth = grid.find('colgroup:first').find('col:eq(' + Index + ')').width();
                          grid.find('colgroup').find('col:eq(' + Index + ')').width(columnwidth-20);
                }
            };


        $(".Increase").click(IncreaseWidth);

        $(".Decrease").click(DecreaseWidth);


    });
```

Any solutions to this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having similar issue, here's quick work around I used to deal with column resize problem.

Key observation on this problem is that grid column will realign properly once user adjusts the column manually.

So, in my workaround, I basically hide and show first column and force grid columns to re-size and automatically realign columns properly. Column must re-size after grid receive all its data though. I used amplify for custom messaging, but that implementation detail is not crucial as long as code can automatically force column re-size on grid after data is received.

For example,

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            type: 'json',
            transport: {
                read: config.AppBasePath + '/Home/GetSomething',
                parameterMap: function (data, type) {
                    if (type == 'read') {
                        return {
                            id: messageId
                        };
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 10,
            requestEnd: function (e) {
                amplify.publish(config.Messages.ShowWindowComplete);
            }
        }),           

    ....


    amplify.subscribe(config.Messages.ShowWindowComplete, function () {
        messageHistoryKendoGridElem.data('kendoGrid').hideColumn(1);
        messageHistoryKendoGridElem.data('kendoGrid').showColumn(1);
    });
```

Hope this help anyone who is facing similar issue.